# Правильно ли выражение "нет, я не человек, а нечто другое"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли выражение "нет, я не человек, а нечто другое"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, сомнения вызывает "*нечто*" - можно ли это отнести к себе. **Можно**, поскольку после отрицания своего отношения к роду людскому лирический герой относит себя к существам (или сущностям), на которые нельзя сослаться местоимением "некто" (или ещё как-либо), которое всегда указывает на *людей* или животных того же вида, об особях которого идёт речь (в специфическом сюжете о котах ещё можно себе представить "*некто* Барсик").